# Xcode 7 how to set app version?

Tags: xcode

[image]

I no longer have the ability to set my app version (`1.2.3 (4)`) as documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

I accepted an Xcode update and now only have `Info` and `Build Settings`.  Where'd it go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between editing the *project* and editing the *app target*. You are editing the project. But what you want is the app target.

That little menu that says "demo" at the top left (second row) of your screenshot will switch between them.

Answer (score 1):

Click here and change the target. You'll get the options back which actually belong to your app target and not to your project.

[image]

Comment: Has nothing to do with "scheme".

Comment: Still not right. The project is not a target. It's the project.